# Push object to empty array if not exist angularjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, json

I created an array is empty. I want to push unique object. I want to use for loop. But firstly array length is zero. So doesnt work for loop. How can I do?

```
$scope.arr=[];
$scope.result=[
   {category: "Home", categoryInt: 1, categoryPercent:50},
   {category: "Office", categoryInt: 1, categoryPercent:25},
   {category: "Office", categoryInt: 1, categoryPercent:25},
   {category: "Office", categoryInt: 1, categoryPercent:25}
[
for(var z=0; z<$scope.arr.length; z++){
    if ($scope.arr[z].percent === $scope.result[a].categoryPercent) {
        return;
    } else {
        $scope.arr.push({category: $scope.result[a].category, percent: $scope.result[a].categoryPercent, categoryInt: $scope.result[a].categoryInt});                                             
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you not declare the object in question as a variable and then use the Array.include() function as a check in a conditional statement?

Comment: Thanks for answer I used Array.include function. When loop working always result return false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to have array of object of unique objects. Below is working code:

```js
let arr = [];
var result = [{category:"Home",categoryInt:1,categoryPercent:50},{category:"Office",categoryInt:1,categoryPercent:25},{category:"Office",categoryInt:1,categoryPercent:25},{category:"Office",categoryInt:1,categoryPercent:25}];

arr = Object.values(result.reduce((acc, cur) => Object.assign(acc, {
  [cur.categoryPercent]: cur
}), {}));

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but I shouldn't reduce $scope.result. Because I have to use another loops

Comment: @Hermes updated answer. It will not change your `result`. Check now.

Comment: Thats worked but doesnt work perfectly. Some values is repeated. How can I use multi filter? For example I want to use categoryPercent and categoryInt

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: Your answer is correct but. $scope.result has more than property. I have written some property. When I use your code some values pushed to $scope.arr. So I think I have to use multi filter for example arr = Object.values(result.reduce((acc, cur) => Object.assign(acc, {
  [cur.categoryPercent, cur.categoryInt ]: cur
}), {}));